# For broken images, is it specified anywhere whether browsers are supposed to obey width/height attributes/CSS or consider them replaced elements?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I noticed that there is very different behavior among browser of what gets shown when display:inline images are broken. When an image is broken, is there supposed to be any standard behavior, at least in terms of whether width and height (HTML attributes or CSS) are still obeyed, and whether the element still gets treated as a replaced element?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#img-error doesn't seem to define this. Is there something supplementary somewhere that does? I'm used to different browsers having things like different broken image icons since the earliest graphical browsers, but I thought that at least layout-related stuff would be specified somewhere now. Is this not the case?

When src is 404ed, there is an alt attribute, and display is left as the default (inline):

- Chrome lays out the images according to their padding and margin while ignoring any width and height attributes/CSS.
- Like Chrome, Firefox pushes out the borders according to the padding (and, like Chrome, ignores any width and height attributes/CSS), but overlaps the borders with neighboring content, because the flow is set purely by the alt text, not its content+padding+border+margin.
- Safari and Edge obey the width/height dimensions, like all browsers do if you set display:inline-block.
- There seem to be differences in whether the broken image element is treated as replaced: In the respective browsers' DOM inspectors, all of the browsers (even Safari and Edge, which obey the dimensions even when the src is not working) indicate they default IMG elements to display:inline. However, the fact that the image elements get vertical margins applied (except for the case of Firefox) seems to show they are still being treated as replaced elements even while broken, except in the case of Firefox. (That is, margin-top and margin-bottom are supposed to have no effect on display:inline *non-replaced* elements, so Firefox apparently sort of treats the broken images as non-replaced elements.) On the other hand, it's only in Chrome that you can have an img::before{content:'text'} pseudoelement show up in a broken image, like you would in a non-replaced element.

Other things I noticed in the broken images below:

- Chrome for some reason only shows a broken image icon when there's non-zero-length alt string or no alt attribute at all. Firefox only shows a broken image icon when there's no alt attribute at all. Safari and Edge show a broken image icon in all cases.
- Chrome and Firefox show a placeholder content bounding box for missing content only when there's no alt attribute. Safari show a content bounding box always, Edge shows no content bounding box in any case.
- If display:inline-block is applied and there is no working src and the alt string is not zero length, Chrome and Firefox make the baseline of subsequent text on the line shifted up. (See the first line in the "Forced inline-block" section below.) This does not happen in Safari or Edge.

(Images with no alt attributes are not actually valid HTML, but are shown for comparison of behavior.)

Tested in Chrome 64, Firefox 58, Safari 11, EdgeHTML 16.16299

```css
img{
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:1em;
  padding:1em;
}

.force-ib-images img{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="x" width="300" height="120" alt="alttext"> (alt="alttext") <br>
<img src="x" width="300" height="120" alt=""         > (alt="")<br>
<img src="x" width="300" height="120" alt            > (alt)<br>
<img src="x" width="300" height="120"                > (no alt attribute)<br>

<hr>

<h3>
  with height/width set via css:
</h3>

<img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt="alttext"> (alt="alttext") <br>
<img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt=""         > (alt="")<br>
<img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt            > (alt)<br>
<img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px"                > (no alt attribute)<br>

<hr>

<div class="force-ib-images">

  <h3>
    Forced inline-block:
  </h3>

  <img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt="alttext"> (alt="alttext") <br>
  <img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt=""         > (alt="")<br>
  <img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px" alt            > (alt)<br>
  <img src="x" style="width:300px; height:120px"                > (no alt attribute)<br>

</div>


<hr>

  <h3>
    With image:
  </h3>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/FQFzBJh.png" width="300" height="120" alt="an image">
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/upkt6p7p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [HTML 5.3 10.4.2 Images](https://w3c.github.io/html/rendering.html#replaced-elements-images): <sub>([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#images-3))</sub>

> If the element is an img element that represents some text and the
>   user agent does not expect this to change
>
> The user agent is expected to treat the element as a non-replaced phrasing 
>   element whose content is the text, optionally with an icon
>   indicating that an image is missing, so that the user can request the
>   image be displayed or investigate why it is not rendering. In
>   non-graphical contexts, such an icon should be omitted.

So it should be a non-replaced element when the image is broken.

But note that browsers do not have to be compliant with section 10. "is expected" means that the browser only need comply if it claims to do so.

> User agents are not required to present HTML documents in any particular way. However, this section provides a set of suggestions for rendering HTML documents that, if followed, are likely to lead to a user experience that closely resembles the experience intended by the documents' authors. [...] For the purposes of conformance for user agents designated as supporting the suggested default rendering, the term "expected" in this section has the same conformance implications as "must". ([10 Rendering](https://w3c.github.io/html/rendering.html#rendering))<sub>([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendering))</sub>

Comment: Hmm, I guess the question would then be whether the browsers claim to abide by the expectation. My understanding, according to the "HTML 5.3 10.4.2 Images" excerpt above, is that Firefox is the one that comes closest to meeting the expectation in terms of layout (it doesn't apply margin-top and margin-bottom -- as evidenced by the overlapping boxes in the sample above), although Chrome treats it closer to expectation of a non-replaced element in terms of allowing the display of ::before and ::after pseudoelements.